# Analog of \pdfelapsedtime for LuaTeX and XeTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, profiling

In pdfTeX, the `\pdfelapsedtime` primitive gives access to the time since this pdfTeX run was started, in "scaled seconds" (1/65536 seconds). This is useful to benchmark code: repeat it many times, and test the time it takes.

```
\newcount\benchmarkcount
\long\def\tenfold#1{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}
\long\edef\thousandfold{\tenfold{\tenfold{\tenfold{#1}}}}
\long\def\benchmark#1{%
  \benchmarkcount\pdfelapsedtime
  \thousandfold{#1}%
  \typeout{\the\dimexpr\pdfelapsedtime sp-\benchmarkcount sp miliseconds}%
}
```

Is it possible to have access to the time in a similar way in XeTeX and/or LuaTeX?

Comment: Are you sure, your original code gives you milliseconds and not seconds?

Comment: @Andy: I almost replied that you were right, but in fact, since I'm performing the code 1000 times (three uses of `\tenfold`), the total time in seconds is the time in milliseconds taken by one copy of the code. [Then, there is a typo, I should've written "millisecond".]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After some help from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36314/char-to-integer-cast-in-latex), the following code seems to be pretty close to the original primitive. We look at the pdflatex release notes (2005-08-01) first

> - `\pdfelapsedtime` is a read-only integer that (initially) returns the
>       amount of time passed since the start of this run. This amount is given
>       in `scaled seconds': the value 65536 counts as one second. If more time
>       has passed than 32767 seconds, (2^31)-1 will be returned.
> - `\pdfresettimer` updates the internal timer, such that subsequent calls to
>       `\pdfelapsedtime` will restart from 0.

Now, the try to reimplement in user space:

```
\directlua{pdfelapsedtimer_basetime=0}
```

`os.clock()` counts from the start of lua, so it `pdfelapsedtimer_basetime` is set to zero. No need to read the initial `os.clock()` value, it is supposed to be 0 anyway. From lua.org:

> The os.clock function returns the number of seconds of CPU time for
>   the program. Its typical use is to benchmark a piece of code

If the user want to reset it, the pdflatex primitive is `\pdfresettimer`. In that case, we read out `os.clock()` and store it in `pdfelapsedtimer_basetime` to subtract the offset later.

```
\protected\def\pdfresettimer{\directlua{pdfelapsedtimer_basetime = os.clock()}}
```

Finally, the `\pdfelapsedtime` macro subtracts the offset to get seconds, multiplies by 65536 to get scaled seconds, adds 0.5 to allow the function `math.floor` proper rounding and returns an integer. We need an integer and not characters in the token stream, therefore, `\numexpr` is utilized.

```
\protected\def\pdfelapsedtime{\numexpr\directlua{tex.print(math.floor((os.clock()-pdfelapsedtimer_basetime)*65536+0.5))}\relax}
```

The following MWE is an implementation for the original question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\benchmarkcount
\long\def\tenfold#1{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}
\long\edef\thousandfold#1{\tenfold{\tenfold{\tenfold{#1}}}}
\long\def\benchmark#1{%
  \benchmarkcount\pdfelapsedtime
  \thousandfold{#1}%
  \typeout{\the\dimexpr\pdfelapsedtime sp-\benchmarkcount  sp}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\directlua{pdfelapsedtimer_basetime=0}
\protected\def\pdfresettimer{\directlua{pdfelapsedtimer_basetime = os.clock()}}
\protected\def\pdfelapsedtime{\numexpr\directlua{tex.print(math.floor((os.clock()-pdfelapsedtimer_basetime)*65536+0.5))}\relax}

\begin{document}
\benchmark{\lipsum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Since I want to put that into a package, I guess I shouldn't call the variable `x`, though. Is there a good method for name scoping?

Comment: If you could code these macros to behave like the original primitives, then they would be good candidates for the `pdftexcmds` package which defines some of the missing pdftex primitives for LuaTeX.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Use a lua table table, e.g. `elapsedtime = {} elapsedtime.start = os.clock()`, this is the lua name scoping way.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: I would try to do Martins suggestion, if someone is not already doing that. Otherwise I take it as an exercise :)

Comment: @Andy: Sorry, I don't have time at the moment, so it would be great if you can do that and sent it to Heiko Oberdiek.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Heiko Oberdiek edited and added the macros in the next version of `pdftexcmds`.

Comment: @Andy: thanks for your work. I think it is a useful addition to Heiko's `pdftexcmds`.