# What is the macro/primitive for the current run time?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, compiling

I've seen (I don't know where) a couple of interesting metadata-oriented control sequences, and I was wondering if such a sequence exists for the job runtime.  I can't expect it to give me the *total* run-time, but the run-time at that specific point would work well enough.  I'm putting in a rather braggy [colophon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63468/), for the interested.

My use case would be something like

```
\documentclass{silly}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

This document was typeset with \XeTeX, which is based on the \TeX\ typesetting
system by Dr.~Donald~Knuth... which is very fast.  This entire work took only
\pdfjobtime\ seconds to compile!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Analog of `\pdfelapsedtime` for LuaTeX and XeTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32507/5764)

Comment: @Werner I think it's a duplicate really,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'd agree with that, even though the (apparently unavoidable) lack of a XeTeX realization of the command is a little depressing.

Comment: Also related: [Using shell escape to access system time](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65176/17423)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pdftex and luatex have `\pdfelapsedtime` but xetex doesn't. For total run time you can always go

```
time xelatex myfile
```

and input the result on the next run

Comment: As an addendum - for those stuck on Windows, there is no `time` command directly available in the shell.  However, PowerShell offers something good enough for me: `Measure-Command {xelatex file}`.