# Page by page compilation time

Tags: xetex

I am trying to locate the bottlenecks in compilation for a very large document.

The accepted answer to [this Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210139/pdflatex-how-to-find-bottleneck-of-long-compiling-time-for-my-document) addresses the problem in a neat way
but the method only works for pdflatex (and not for LuaTeX and XeTeX) because the `\pdfelapsedtime` primitive is only available in pdflatex.

However [this Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32507/analog-of-pdfelapsedtime-for-luatex-and-xetex) creates a `\pdfelapsedtime` analogue for LuaTex.

The question is how to do in XeTeX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since XeTeX does not have timekeeping capabilities, the shell escape feature is left. The disadvantage is the large overhead of running external programs with duration variations.

The following example runs with plain and LaTeX formats. It is written for Perl under Linux and requires the `-shell-escape` switch:

```
xetex -shell-escape test
xelatex -shell-escape test
```

The interface is (macros names are prefixed with `xetk`):

- `\xetkresettimer` is similar to `\pdfresettimer` the timer is reset.
- `\xetksetelapsedtime` gets the current time difference to the last call of `\xetkresettimer`.
- `\xetkelapsedtime` contains the time in seconds as decimal number, set by `\xetksetelapsedtime`.

File `test.tex`:

```
\catcode`\@=11 % \makeatletter

\newread\xetk@pipe
\def\xetk@resetargs{}

\def\xetkresettimer{%
  \begingroup
    % the end of line character must be disabled,
    % otherwise it could add active characters, ...
    \endlinechar=-1 %
    \openin\xetk@pipe="|perl -e '%
      use Time::HiRes qw[gettimeofday];%
      @t=gettimeofday;%
      print qq[@t]%
    '"\relax
    \global\read\xetk@pipe to\xetk@resetargs
    \closein\xetk@pipe
  \endgroup
}
\xetkresettimer
\wlog{XeTeX timekeeping initialization: \xetk@resetargs}
\def\xetkelapsedtime{0}

\edef\xetksetelapsedtime{%
  \begingroup
    \endlinechar=-1 %
    \openin\xetk@pipe="|perl -e '%
      use Time::HiRes qw[tv_interval];%
      print tv_interval(\string\@ARGV)%
    ' -- \noexpand\xetk@resetargs"\relax
    \global\read\xetk@pipe to\noexpand\xetkelapsedtime
    \closein\xetk@pipe
  \endgroup
}

%%% Testing

\def\test{%
  \xetkresettimer
  \xetksetelapsedtime
  \immediate\write16{* Elapsed time: \xetkelapsedtime\space s}%
}

\test
\test
\test
\test
\test

\csname @@end\endcsname\end % end job
```

Macro `\test` resets the timer (external program is called), does nothing
and calls again the external program to get the time difference:

```
* Elapsed time: 0.032371 s
* Elapsed time: 0.032007 s
* Elapsed time: 0.035123 s
* Elapsed time: 0.032473 s
* Elapsed time: 0.033759 s
```

Comment: Wow that's comprehensive. I'm on windows and am going to take some time to work out a shell equivalent - but am marking as the accepted answer in the interim.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn I am working on a more elaborate version including a small C program to reduce the runtime of the external program.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn Running the Perl code from the command line is quite tricky because of quoting problems. The outer layer of double quotes are required by XeTeX to support spaces. But the implementation prevents, that the double quote can be used inside the program call which is quite bad here. In Linux I can use single quotes for the command line argument for the Perl run option `-e` and the Perl language operator `qq//` for double quote strings. On Windows it might be easier to use an installed external program without the need for further quoting, when calling the program with options.